# Random point from a multidimensional ball in Python

Tags: python, random

I would like to draw points from a n-dimensional ball.

I know how to do it for 2D ball, but it is tricky for more dimensions.

Is there any built-in function to do it? If not, what is the simplest effective implementation?

My solution for 2D case

```
phi = 2.0 * 180.0 * rand.random()
radius = math.sqrt(rand.random()) * 0.5
point = [0.5 + radius * math.cos(phi), 0.5 + radius * math.sin(phi)]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what do you want? Besides, it's a good idea to post your code that solved your problem in the 2d-dimension

Comment: Do uniform point-on-surface sampling as described in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html. Then sample radius as R*np.random.random()**(1/n). Multiply point on surface by radius and get point in the n-dimension ball.